# Is this possible to set the environment variable in docker container after it build?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, apache-spark, pyspark

How can set the environment variable in docker container after it has been build?

Here i have created a docker container and installed python and pyspark

Now how do can set the environment variable for both?

There is no bashrc file found to be created inside the container..

Appreciated for the help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
docker run -e "foo=bar" ...
```

See [environment-variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare environment variables for your container either at build time, in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM busybox
ENV foo bar
```

---

At runtime, you have multiple options to instantiate new environment variables, or override those declared in the Dockerfile.

In-line:

```
docker run -e "foo=bar" busybox
```

From an .env file:

```
docker run --env-file .env busibox
```

```
cat .env

foo=bar
```

Runtime variables can also be passed in the compose file:

```
web:
  env_file:
    - .env
#OR
  environment:
    - foo=bar
```